# Load CMS Block or PHTML file after page load

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript, dynamic

I have a PHTML file that loads products based on the data I send via the set data method.

e.g `->setData('xxx', $xxx)`

I call this file in another PHTML file numerous times to show all products.

This means it is taking a while for the page to load.

Is there a way I can load the PHTML file or a CMS Block after page load or on click?

I am using this to show the file:

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setData('xxx', $xxx)->setTemplate('xxx/xxx.phtml')->toHtml();
```

Or is there a way to load PHTML or CMS Block in an iframe?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by Ajax e.g. add this in your template file :

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    jQuery.get( "http://example.com/mymodule/index/some", function( data ) {
          console.log(data); // replace this output in your page
    });
});
```

Create a function in any controller then add this code e.g.

```
class Paras_Mymodule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{


     public function someAction() {
        $html = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setData('xxx', $xxx)->setTemplate('xxx/xxx.phtml')->toHtml();               
        echo $html;
    }
}
```

I know this is not complete solution but It will help you.